# OpenId Connect Relying party implementation in Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, openid-connect, liferay-ide, openid-provider

I am using Liferay CE 6.2 for my application. My application is a relying party and we want to do openId connect relying party implementation in Liferay. Can someone please guide me on this?

Answer (score 0):

liferay 6.2 does not support that out of the box ... while being at  liferay Devcon this week (4.11.2017 /6.11.2017) I have heard that it will be a feature in 7.1...

so every start with 6.2, is implementing it by yourself, which starts with the question which app server are you going to use and which is the issuing party of your jwt tokens ?